# If column a contains x find y in same row as x and display value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

CLOSED: Thanks alot, it's all sorted!

The title pretty much sums it up. I am pulling a dataset and pasting it into a seperate sheet(in this instance "CSV") and I need the first sheet to look down a particular column (in this instance H) and search for a particular value (in the instance A2 or "3019") and once located search for the value in another column of the same row (in this instance column K).

So far I have got the formula to search for it =IF(CSV!H2:H100=A2,"yes") and it seems to sporadically work (sometimes reading "yes", sometimes reading "FALSE")

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Feel free to get me to clarify as required.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,CSV!$H$2:$K$100,4,0)
```

formula searching value of `A2` in `CSV!H2:H100` and if found, returns corresponding value from column `K`. If nothing found, it returns `#N/A!` error. However you can handle this case.
For Excel 2007 and later:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,CSV!H2:K100,4,0),"nothing found")
```

For Excel 2003:

```
IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,CSV!H2:K100,4,0)),"nothing found",VLOOKUP(A2,CSV!H2:K100,4,0))
```